# WoL missing in BIOS, will it work?

Tags: 12.04, networking, bios, wakeonlan

From [help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan)

> In order to use WoL it must be supported and enabled as necessary in the BIOS, NIC and other network hardware (routers, switches etc). You may also need to configure some software if things don't work out-of-the-box.

Does this mean that I must have WoL enabled in all 3 items or just one of them?

My question is because the NIC says:

```
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
```

Which, means that WoL is present and enabled. However, there is no option in the BIOS (it's a eeeBox 1503) to enable WoL. Actually, it loads a simple UEFI, not exactly the BIOS, so that is probably why I don't see any advanced option.

The router supports WakeOnLan. So, the BIOS is the only item I can't enable it. Will I need to find a way to enable it there, or having it enabled on the NIC is enough?

**EDIT**

It was not working because I was trying to *power up* when the machine is completely off and not *wake up* from sleep/suspend mode. I want to power up, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

[The answer provided by psusi](https://askubuntu.com/a/248854/126822) answers my question. Using `ethtool` to enable WoL is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bios simply controls the default setting.  It can be changed with `ethtool`, and in your case, is already enabled, but only for magic packet wake.

Comment: Although I still can't wake up the machine, your reply answers my question. I don't need to change anything in the BIOS to enable it.

Comment: Never mind. It is working. I guess the problem was that I was trying to _power up_, not _wake up_. Not sure if there is a difference. But what I really want is to power up the machine in case it shutdown due to power failure.

Answer (score 2):

When you have your PC off, and the network cable plugged into it, do you see activity on the network port? i.e. flashing green or amber lights? If so, then WOL is enabled. The easiest way to tell is just to try. :-)

Comment: No, there is no activity. The LED for this machine is off. But the other machine that works, the LED is also off and it wakes up when requested.

Comment: Yeah, it only tells you if it's on and working, not if it's off/not-working. Some NICs don't blink on WOL traffic.